# Как правильно поставить задержку при анимации?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Вообщем, хочу сделать анимацию, ставлю задержку 2 секунды, но элемент остается на странице, и по истечению этих двух секунд делает анимацию. Как сделать так, чтобы он сначала был невидимым, и только при начале анимации появлялся?

```
.fr-btn__ {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50px;  height: 100px;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  animation: zoomIn 2s 2s, spin 4s infinite 2s forwards;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>floydpower | dev</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:ital,wght@1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="main-container">Привет, я <span class="coder-name">флойдпавер,</span><br>разработчик на Python.</h1>
  <a href="#about" class="about-link">
    <div class="fr-btn__">
      <div class='scroll-down'>ᐯ</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Opacity` из нуля в единицу через **fadeIn**, задержку для `spin` убрать.

```css
.fr-btn__ {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  opacity: 0; /* Начальное значение непрозрачности */
  animation: fadeIn 2s 2s forwards, spin 4s infinite forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>floydpower | dev</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:ital,wght@1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#about" class="about-link">
    <div class="fr-btn__">
      <div class='scroll-down'>ᐯ</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```